# A dash or a hyphen in the sentence "Owls are 20-30 cm long," and what's the pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, punctuation

> Owls are 20-30 cm long.

My question is silly but nevertheless: is it a hyphen or a dash here? And how is the "20-30" pronounced?

Comment: For the record, the vast majority of English speakers would not notice or care about the written form, unless trying to copy/paste a non-ASCII character broke some other tool they're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be neither a hyphen (-) nor an 'em dash' (—) but an 'en dash' (–). It is spoken "twenty to thirty centimeters".

Comment: Is it possible to omit this "to" in speech?

Comment: @Yulia Not usually when you are speaking of a range within several values falls. Yes, if you are offering an approximation of a single value; but this will ordinarily represent a colloquial shortening of *20 **or** 30*, and will ordinarily be written either that way or (in a transcript) as "20,30".

Comment: I always thought the hyphen was used for ranges, not the dash. (That's what [this online resource](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/3/7/98/) says, too.) That said, I don't want to get dogmatic about it; I'd be surprised if no other style guides were more in line with what you are saying.

Comment: And in an informal context, a hyphen is preferable to an em dash.

Comment: This is what I know from typesetting. The traditional rule for individuals might be different since it would have been established before word processors—typewriters almost certainly would have had only hyphens, not allowing for such fine distinctions.

Comment: [Here's a style guide with en-dash usage](http://site.uit.no/english/punctuation/hyphen/) supporting this answer.

Comment: @J.R. different style guides vary, and you can't call either one wrong, but most typographers will say that an en dash simply looks better with figures.

Answer (score 4):

It's a hyphen. And it's pronounced "twenty to thirty".

In typography, a hyphen is shorter than a dash. If whatever you are using to create a document does not have a dash character, it is common to use two hyphens in a row instead, as in "--".

A hyphen is used:

(a) Between two parts of some compound words, such as "well-known", as in, "He is a very well-known man."

(b) Between parts of an identifying code or number, like a phone number or part number. For example, "My phone number is 516-555-1234."

(c) Between elements of a range, as in your example. "We will ship in 2-3 weeks."

A dash is used between clauses in a sentence. For example, "I think -- and I am not sure about this -- that Sally is in her office." A dash can be used pretty much anywhere a comma could be used between clauses. It tends to signal to the reader a separation that is more than a comma but not as much as breaking into multiple sentences.

Comment: The guidance here matches what I found in the [Purdue OWL](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/3/7/98/).

Comment: "The guidance here matches what I found in the Purdue OWL" - which doesn't necessarily mean it is correct!

Comment: @alephzero - I agree. More specifically, it doesn't mean contrary advice *isn't* correct. I was merely leaving a corroborating source since none was provided in this answer.